# veth.ko missing

Tags: kernel, raspberrypi, lxd

On a Raspberry Pi 4, running Ubuntu Focal 64bit.  LXD keeps getting broken, and it seems like it's because the kernel module veth.ko is missing.

In an attempt to restore it I did:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-5.4.0-1012-raspi --reinstall
```

This restores veth.ko and makes LXD work.  However, if I reboot, veth.ko is deleted.  Is there some configuration I need to change somewhere that's currently removing veth.ko for 'reasons'?

Answer (score 1):

The package `cloud-initramfs-copymods` sets up /usr/lib/modules from the initramfs found in /boot/firmware. You can choose to add the modules you need to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and regenerate the initramfs, or to remove the `cloud-initramfs-copymods` package to stop this behavior.

I chose to remove the `cloud-initramfs-copymods` package all of my problems disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install
`linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-1008-raspi_5.13.0-1008.9_arm64.deb`
in order to get veth.ko installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for at least more than one year the Ubuntu image for raspberry pi do not include the necessary module. **Despite that at least in their latest release including LXC/LXD by default**.......

Error message:
~lxc start container

`Error: Failed preparing container for start: Failed to start device “eth0”: Failed to create the veth interfaces veth34cbc1ee and veth84f13473: Failed to run: ip link add veth34cbc1ee type veth peer name veth84f13473: Error: Unknown device type.`

On Ubuntu 21.10 I fixed it by running:
`sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi`

Note: I did not need to remove the "cloud-initramfs-copymods" package mentioned, my new modules survived a reboot. So some progress at least.